# Are there any way of enabling the search feature for vs code webview?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, webview, vscode-extensions

I am making an extension for VS Code where I show html5 articles in a webview.
I've noticed I can't search through the document using the find (ctrl + f) feature.
I am wondering if there is any way to enable it, or maybe implement it using js/ts.
The best idea I've got so far is to detect if the user uses the ctrl + f shortcut and make my own search capabilities with window.find(). I'm not sure jet whether or not it will work, and it feels like an non optimal solution.
Are there any way of enabling the search feature for vs code webview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the webview panel options when creating the webview:

```
    /**
     * Content settings for a webview panel.
     */
    export interface WebviewPanelOptions {
        /**
         * Controls if the find widget is enabled in the panel.
         *
         * Defaults to false.
         */
        readonly enableFindWidget?: boolean;
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for late response.
Thanks it worked!

If someone have the same question as I did:
I was looking at the wrong place in the documentation: https://vshaxe.github.io/vscode-extern/vscode/WebviewOptions.html
I actually needed to look here:
https://vshaxe.github.io/vscode-extern/vscode/WebviewPanelOptions.html

Comment: If the answer was useful for you then please accept it (checkmark on the left). If you think it's worth you can even upvote it (above the checkmark).

Comment: Thx, did it now. I sadly do not have enough reputation to upvote the post, and therefore I just assumed I could not accept the answer, but I see now that it is not correct.

Comment: Whilst that works, what you seem to be unable to do is actually "take part" in the search. It doesn't seem to be something you can modify the behaviour of for example. I'd really like to be able to intercept that find and do something different, but you don't appear to be able to as far as I can see